# fastest search - list of string or list int

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I'm designing a probably very large database (>5 millions records and raising fast) in mongodb + python. One of the needed search to be done is to find documents which contain at least one string given a list of strings. For example, the document below has a tag field (array of strings) like:

```
doc1: {
 _id: 8383929,
 title: "title doc1 info desc",
 tag: ['java', 'php', 'javascript', 'html']
},
doc2: {
 _id: 11189828,
 title: "title doc2 another",
 score: 6,
 tag: ['php', 'html']
}
```

The user provide an input search, as a list of string:

```
query_list = ['java','python']
```

Mongo will return `doc1` because there is an intersection between `doc1.tag` and `query_list` (at least one common string - in this 'java')
I'm very suspicious that this search will not scale well.
So, my question is: if I replace each string by a number (int), like an enum type, probably the cost of comparison will be lower, right? The schema could be:

```
doc1: {
 tag = [20, 5, 4, 7]
}
doc2: {
 tag = [5, 7]
}
```

and

```
query_list = [20, 42]
```

do you think this will be a good choice, or there is a better option to go?

Comment: how about elasticsearch for things like this? free test search in many documents

Comment: I would like to avoid another library/api/service integration now but would consider  elasticsearch for sure in case of mongodb bottleneck

Comment: Do you want fuzzy matching for common misspellings, regional variation, lemmatization, etc.? If so, a term-to-integer method might not be ideal.

Comment: I don't need to worry about misspellings/variations/substrings etc.., bc the tags  (string) are unique, so, therefore, the search only needs to perform an exact string match. my problem is how to optimize an intersection operation between two sets, in the example the intersection(doc.tag, query_list) for hundreds thousands records.

Comment: If you index the tag field, the documents will be found by reading the index not comparison with each document, so the performance should be about the same.